# how to flip uyvy (4:2:2) image horizontally using only std libs in c?

Tags: c, image, image-rotation

I don't think I am able to get the dimensions right and I am getting the wrong output output

```
for (int y = 0; y < 1280; ++y)
    {
        fread(pixel, 2*1086, 1, fIn);
        for (int x = 542; x >= 0; x--)
        {
            fwrite((pixel+x), 4, 1, fOut);

        }

     }
```

Comment: Can you show how you are loading in the image?

Comment: I don't know whether `fread()` and `fwrite()` are right tools for the job, but you are not SWAPPING the pixels, you are just overwriting some of them

Comment: How wide is your image? 2·1086 ≠ 4·542. What is the type of `pixel`? That's important for determining what `pixel + x` means.

Comment: According to [this page](https://www.theimagingsource.com/support/documentation/ic-imaging-control-cpp/PixelformatUYVY.htm), you should also swap the brightnesses of two adjacent pixels. Anyway, this question lacks important information. "I am getting the wrong output" is not a useful description of your problem. What output do you get? What did you expect?